# Can't get jQuery to enqueue into post edit script

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

In the code below, unless I hardcode a reference to the jQuery library, my jQuery bits on the page do not work. What's wrong with the enqueue method I'm trying to use?

In functions.php:

```
if(is_admin())
{

/* LOAD ADMIN SCRIPTS
**********************************/
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions_private.php');

}
```

In functions_private.php:

```
if( 'post.php' == $pagenow )
{

    add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_load_ui_script');

    function my_load_ui_script()
    {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    ?>
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script>
        if(typeof jQuery!="undefined"){
            alert("You have jQuery loaded");//WILL NOT FIRE UNLESS I HARDCODE JQUERY INCLUDE
        }           

        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
        //jquery bits go here
        }

    }//END FUNCTION 

}//END IF
```

Comment: As the question is about JS event listeners it's therefore *off-topic*. Close voted.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook to add your own custom script. Put it in an external file, and use `wp_localize_script` to pass any data from php to javascript. jQuery is already used on the admin side, adding a script tag sourcing it from google will break things.

```
function wpa80418_admin_enqueue( $hook ) {
    if( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my_custom_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa80418_admin_enqueue' );
```

Comment: I'm not trying to use my own script. I'm trying to use the wordpress copy of jquery. Unfortunately, its not working. When I replace admin_print_scripts with admin_enqueue_scripts it does not work either.

Comment: Try the `admin_footer` hook

Comment: +1 diggy! That works but now my script has apparently foobarred the wordpress admin. None of the panels will toggle open/close. My script works fine though. I'm getting a console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: because you're adding your own copy of jquery from an external source, again, this will break the admin UI as you have seen. WordPress already comes with jQuery, it should already be included on most admin pages, as all the javascript in the admin UI uses it. don't inject script tags directly into the page, enqueue external files for your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress jQuery does not support $ by default.

First Add jQuery.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(array('jquery'));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

replace this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
        //jquery bits go here
        }
```

with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

Comment: I'm not using the $ character in my jquery code, so this is not really pertinent to the question. My problem is that jquery is not loading at all (see updated question)

Comment: see updated answare!

Answer (score 0):

The `admin_footer` hook proves to be the right hook for Scott B's code. However, it is generally recommended to enqueue scripts (and declare their jQuery dependency) as described in the answer of @Milo

Answer (score 0):

### Event listeners

Simple:

- The script executes immediately when you run it, as it doesn't use any javascript event listener like waiting until the DOM or the window or whatever loaded.
- The enqueued script (jQuery) will be rendered on its appropriate hooks: In the head or - if enqueued mid-page - in the footer.

Therefore jQuery is simply not available when you call it.